# Why does the dropdown menu not appear on the mobile and disappear quickly when you click on it? It only works with flash؟

Tags: html, css

*******start html******************

```
    <a href="">ابحث في الموقع</a>
        <ul class="submenu">
        <li><a href="">الرئيسيه</a></li>
        <li><a href="">تواصل معنا </a></li>    
        <li><a href="">المدونه </a></li>    
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

start *******************css

```
 ul{margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 list-style: none;}

 a{text-decoration: none;}
 .navigation{width:300px;
 margin: 20px auto;}

 .menu{position: relative;}
 .submenu{position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  padding: 5px;
  display: none;}
```

**************when hover on mobile appear flash only and disappear again

```
 .menu:hover .submenu{display: block;}
```

Comment: There is no hover on mobiles

Answer (score 0):

Because you use :hover it disappears again. To toggle the submenu you could use javascript to change the class.

So add `onclick="myFunction()"` to the element you want to click, and add an id to the element you want to toggle class: `<ul id="submenu">`.

Then your function (under the other elements to make sure they are loaded before the script):

```
<script>
    function myFunction() {
        var element = document.getElementById("submenu");
        element.classList.toggle("mystyle");
    }
</script>
```

Look [here](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_toggle_class.asp) for a example.